# Groovy unable to load class

Tags: groovy, dependencies, classpath, pdfbox

I'm trying to mess around a little bit with PDFBox and Groovy. I'm trying to figure out the width of a string using the PDType1Font class' getStringWidth() method.

My problem is that everytime I compile and run the code, I get an error saying this:

```
Error:Groovyc: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font due to missing dependency org/apache/fontbox/type1/DamagedFontException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1091)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1069)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.intMain2(GroovycRunner.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.runGroovycInThisProcess(InProcessGroovyc.java:156)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.access$000(InProcessGroovyc.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc$1.call(InProcessGroovyc.java:85)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc$1.call(InProcessGroovyc.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font

float getStringWidth(String text) {
        PDType1Font font = new PDType1Font(PDType1Font.HELVETICA)
        float width = font.getStringWidth(text) / 1000 * 8;

        return width
    }
```

I took down all the irrelevant parts of the code for the sake of clarity.

What is the problem?

UPDATE: I searched a little on how to add an external jar to my classpath in IntelliJ and I found out that I need to go to Project Structure -> Modules  -----> Dependencies, and then I need to configure my library as a dependency.

I tried to do this like this:

[image: img]

But I'm still getting the error message depicted above.

Comment: The code will require the PDFBox jar (and its dependencies, such as fontbox) on the classpath. This can be done with Gradle but for a plain/simple example, check out 'setvars.sh' in this project - https://github.com/peidevs/OpenDataBookClub/tree/master/tools/PDF_Thresher

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I didn't exactly understand what is this setvars.sh file and how it is executed nor when. I also updated this post with and image.

Comment: Your image shows that you have different versions. You need to have fontbox 2.0.3 too, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

According to the OP's [snapshot of the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK1nV.png), he uses these dependencies:

[image: dependencies from snapshot]

This cannot work, the versions of pdfbox and fontbox must match (as remarked by [Tilman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr)). In particular version 2 introduced an overhauled API. Thus, a PDFBox version 2.0.x can hardly be expected to work properly alongside a FONTBox version 1.8.y.

Answer (score -1):

Java convention means you have to declare your code inside a class.

That means each method should be defined inside a class with a relevant name to the methods it wraps.

For example you can use the following code structure:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font

class StringUtils {

    float getStringWidth(String text) {
        PDType1Font font = new PDType1Font(PDType1Font.HELVETICA)
        float width = font.getStringWidth(text) / 1000 * 8;

        return width
    }
}
```

In the example above the StringUtils is the class name the JVM is looking for.

By using that convention the code is compiled into byte code and create the relevant jar, and probably that should solve the error you have.

Note: Make sure your PATH ENV variable includes the code workspace directory with all the relevant third party directories.